# LeetCode Two Sums problem - Result undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

First stack overflow question :)

My code is returning "undefined" as the result. Can someone please tell me why?

Question: Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.

Test Case: Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9 
My Output: undefined 
Correct Output: [0,1]

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    
    // iterate through each element  
    nums.forEach((element, index) => {
      
        // iterate through the rest of the array
        nums.forEach((el, i) => {
            // makes sure it isnt adding the same index
            if(index != i) {
                if(element+el == target){
                    return [index, i];
                }
            }

        })
    })
};
```

Comment: Your `twoSum` does not `return` anything

Comment: if element+el is not equal to the target?

Answer (score 1):

Issue is the `return` statement in `forEach` callback method means return value for the callback method and *not* the actual `twoSum` function.

```js
var twoSum = function(nums, target) {
    let res = [];
    // iterate through each element  
    nums.forEach((element, index) => {
      
        // iterate through the rest of the array
        nums.forEach((el, i) => {
            // makes sure it isnt adding the same index
            if(index != i) {
                if(element+el == target){
                    res = [index, i];
                }
            }

        })
    })
    return res;
};

const nums = [2,7,11,15]
const target = 9
console.log(twoSum(nums, target))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this solution, you can get all results.

```js
var twoSum = function (nums, target) {
    let res = [];
    // iterate through each element
    for (let index = 0; index < nums.length - 1; index++) {
        // iterate through the rest of the array,
        for (let i = index + 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (nums[index] + nums[i] === target) {
                res.push([index, i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
};

const nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
const target = 9
console.log(twoSum(nums, target))
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can use tee Hash Table(Map) to reduce the complexity of the algorithm

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} target
 * @return {number[]}
 */

const twoSum = (nums, target) => {
    const hashMap = new Map();

    for (const i in nums) {
        const num = target - nums[i];
        if (hashMap.has(num)) {
            return [+i, nums.indexOf(num)];
        } else {
            hashMap.set(nums[i], true);
        }
    }
};


console.log(twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9))
```